# Alternative to toggle bolt for toilet roll holder?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

My toilet roll holder comes off the wall every 6-12 months. Regular plastic anchors aren't helping much.

I saw that toggle bolts are a great option, but I only have about 1.5" of depth to work with, and can't find any toggle bolts shorter than 2".

Aside from the asking the hardware store to cut them down for me, are there any recommendations for this scenario please?

Comment: you can't make the toggle bolts any shorter than half the wingspan+thickness of wings + thickness of wall + thickness of holder's eylets; otherwise the wings won't ever "flap out"...

Comment: "*but I only have about 1.5" of depth*"  What kind of wall is the TP holder attached to that only has 1.5" of depth? I use these anchors https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-2-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183821  overkill for a TP holder but it will never come off by itself.

Comment: Indeed, what is the wall? I'd consider opening up a section of wall between studs (assming there are studs) and placing a solid wood board there, then finishing over that, to provide a solid base. Having been through a few rounds of "people getting older" I'd look to mount a grab handle solidly as well while I was at it. If a masonry wall, I'd look to lead anchors.

Comment: have you tried the larger screw in drywall anchors?

Comment: Until we get more info from the OP  then we can not really provide an informed answer.

Comment: @alaskaman thank you all for the comments. It is dry wall, I believe, but there isn't a significant amount of space between this wall and the outside brick wall. Pardon me for not being any more certain. At this point, I am looking at Hollow Wall Anchors, any thoughts on those please?

Comment: Actually, now I am thinking that maybe the Cobra Walldriller #6 might work best. #8 is exactly 1.5" so I'm worried it won't quite fit. Any thoughts on those please?

Comment: "Regular plastic anchors" don't work in drywall for anything more than a small picture frame. Use proper drywall anchors - you'd know if you're using "proper" drywall anchors if the drywall gets torn apart with the anchors if they're pulled out.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the holder to the center of a notebook size piece of wood, sort of like a thin cutting board. Then mount the wood panel to the wall with a screw in each corner. If you like, you can add a bit of glue/adhesive.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. For now, I think my partner wouldn't be too keen on it aesthetically. I may have to come back to this in the future tho if all else fails. Thank you, John.

Comment: The wood can be stained or painted any color to blend with the wall.

Answer (score 0):

How about an off-the-wall suggestion -- have you ever seen a TP pedestal?  We just bought a new house and I was thinking about how to mount new TP holders when I saw this new(?) pedestal thingy.  Sits on the floor and holds a roll or three.

We got one for each bath and I love 'em.  Didn't have to get any wall dust on my hands.

Search for "pedestal TP holder" or the like.

Comment: That's not a shabby idea, thank you. Unfortunately, there isn't much room to put one of those. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

40mm mollys tick all the boxes,  good pull strength, short length, resistant to vibrations.

Comment: "tick all the boxes"  What's this??

Comment: this  idiom: https://www.yourdictionary.com/tick-all-the-boxes

Comment: Well what do you know about that...  learn something new everyday on this site.

Comment: thank you, that's very helpful. I am having a heck of a time finding out what 40mm translates to tho. All I see are notations such as #8 or 1/8S, etc. Any idea what might be the equivalent please? Perhaps it's noted differently in Canada where I am? :)

Comment: 40mm is the over-all length - about 1.5"  I saw some that were 1.25" on amazon but you had to buy 100

Comment: pardon me, Jasen. What I mean is that when I look for these online, they are never listed with the length (neither mm nor inches). It's always just something cryptic like "#8" or "1/8S". I know that means something to some people, but to someone inexperienced it's unclear. I will try to contact the company. I'm not sure why they make it so difficult to get actual lengths (looking at you Cobra).